# Update Transform component of the object in Unity3D from local server via UDP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, udp

for some the solution for my problem may seem to be very obvious and simple, however, unfortunately, I'm a complete beginner in Unity and C# (used to work with Unreal Engine, and now a bit lost here in Unity). 
Basically, what I'm trying to do, is to make an object in Unity to be controlled (position and rotation only) from the data sent by the server (not Unity app) via UDP. So, the message from the server is a string of values for each component of the Transform component (x,y,z, pitch,roll, yaw). And this string is updated every frame (randomly for now)

I've been trying to adopt tons of different codes without any success. 
For example [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c.15900/) or [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/udp-help.365484/)

The source code of the serve looks like this (written not by me):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import requests
import json
import time
import socket

DATA_PREFIX = 'data: '

class Flydra2Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flydra2_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8397/'
        self.session = requests.session()
        r = self.session.get(self.flydra2_url)
        assert(r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)

    def run(self, udp_host, udp_port):
        addr = (udp_host, udp_port)
        print('sending flydra data to UDP %s'%(addr,))
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        events_url = self.flydra2_url + 'events'
        r = self.session.get(events_url,
            stream=True,
            headers={'Accept': 'text/event-stream'},
            )
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
            data = parse_chunk(chunk)
            # print('chunk value: %r'%data)

            try:
                update_dict = data['Update']
            except KeyError:
                continue
            msg = '%s, %s, %s'%(update_dict['x'], update_dict['y'], update_dict['z'])
            sock.sendto(msg,addr)
            # print('send message %r to %s'%(msg,addr))

def serialize(o):
    return

def parse_chunk(chunk):
    lines = chunk.strip().split('\n')
    assert(len(lines)==2)
    assert(lines[0]=='event: flydra2')
    assert(lines[1].startswith(DATA_PREFIX))
    buf = lines[1][len(DATA_PREFIX):]
    data = json.loads(buf)
    return data

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--udp-port", type=int, default=1234,
                        help="UDP port to send pose information")
    parser.add_argument('--udp-host', type=str, default='127.0.0.1',
                        help="UDP host to send pose information")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    flydra2 = Flydra2Proxy()
    flydra2.run(udp_host=args.udp_host, udp_port=args.udp_port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I understand, that learning by doing is not the best strategy, but please, help me with this script for the Unity object, I'm extremely short of time. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working script (must be cleaned though). The object receives the coordinates and updates Transform component properly.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.Sockets;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading;
   public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
       private UdpClient udpServer;
       public GameObject cube;
       private Vector3 tempPos;
       private Thread t;
       public float movementSpeed;
       private long lastSend;
       private IPEndPoint remoteEP;
       private float[] transformPosition = new float[3] ;

       void Start()
       {
           udpServer = new UdpClient(1234);
           t = new Thread(() => {
               while (true) {
                   this.receiveData();

               }
           });
           t.Start();
           t.IsBackground = true;
           remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 41234);
       }

       void Update()
       {
           transform.position = new Vector3(transformPosition[0], transformPosition[1], transformPosition[2]) ;
       }

       private void OnApplicationQuit()
       {
           udpServer.Close();
           t.Abort();
       }

       private void receiveData() {

               byte[] data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);
               if (data.Length > 0)
               {
                   var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                   Debug.Log("Received Data" + str);
                   string[] messageParts = str.Split(',');
                   transformPosition[0] = float.Parse(messageParts[0]) ;
                   transformPosition[1] = float.Parse(messageParts[1]) ;
                   transformPosition[2] = float.Parse(messageParts[2]) ;
               }
       }
   }
```